# membership get rolename and roleid

Tags: asp.net

how can i get rolename and roleid ... 
i want to bind it with dropdown...

Comment: You want a list of all roles available or just for a specific user?

Comment: You only need the rolename in order to add a user or get users. Why not make that the value column of the dropdown?

Comment: Kindly check the posted answers and mark the most helpful one, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 var allRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
```

this will get you a list of all roles in your application.

```
var allRolesForUser = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
```

Note that most of the time, you will be dealing with the Role name,not the ID, and that's how all related methods inside the `Roles` class is working.

Comment: this wont give me the associated roleids

Comment: The scenario is that i want to bind it with a dropdown... in dropdown's text field i will display rolename and in dropdown's value field i will use roleid..

Comment: the question is : what will you use the role ID for ?

for me, I would go with binding both text and value to the RoleName, and use it normally.

if this is not applicable for you, tell me what you gonna do with the ID, thanks.